# How to get different text scaling for different displays?

Tags: 14.04, unity, multiple-monitors, display

I have a laptop with a fairly high resolution on a small display (14"). My external monitor 27" has a lower resolution than the laptop display. I would like for the text to be similar size on both displays which means I would need to be able to scale the text size differently. You can currently have different scales for the menu and title bars, but I haven't figured out how to do it for text (if even possible). I would need some guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

I switch between a 13" 1920x1080 built-in display and an external 19" 1280x1024 one, so I have the same situation. Usually I do it on an app-by-app basis. My main applications are the browser and the terminal.

The terminal is easy, just ctrl + and ctrl - until you reach the font size you want. You can define profiles (Edit -> Profiles) and preset font sizes, then switch between profiles (Terminal -> Change Profile) or even define a default profile for newly-launched terminals.

The browser is more complicated, for Firefox I go to `about:config` and set the `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` value to 1.4 (found experimentally). For more information see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Firefox.

I suggest you google for the applications you want to scale and add "hidpi" to your search to find application-specific tips.

Comment: Having to change fonts constantly is a nuisance, but even more so as I would like to use both screens at the same time. Having a set scaling factor (like for the menu and title bars) would make this a lot easier. Perhaps it doesn't exist yet as a feature...